# How to find the length of an integer array passed as an argument in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to calculate the length of passed array in monkey method. How to do so, as input decays to a pointer inside monkey method...?

```
int monkey(int input1[])
{

    //Write code here
}
```

Constraints:
1) You are not allowed to change the function signature.

Comment: Given the unnecessary constraint, I smell homework.  Are you sure this is not cheating?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: *You are not allowed to change the function signature* well I guess you could set a global var with the array size (or `sizeof(globalArray)/sizeof(int)` if it's a static `[]` array), that global array is the one passed to the *monkey* function... at least it fits the problem description

Answer (score 9):

```
int monkey(int input1[], size_t arraySize)
{

}
```

Passing the size of the array is the most usual method.

Alternatively you can do something like C strings, and add a **sentinel value** to the end of your array (max value, 0, -1, etc) and count the number of elements before this sentinel value.

There are no other alternatives I can think of.

Comment: you are not allowed to change function signature... :D

Comment: @VIK what one's allowed or not should be stated in the question.

Comment: Can you change the input array format itself to add a sentinel value as i suggest?

Answer (score 5):

In the general case, you don't. As it's just a pointer, information about the array is not available.

So you should pass in a size, or wrap it in a struct that contains the size.

Or as it's an array of int, you could use the first value in the array as the size.

Alternatively, depending on your use-case, you could zero-terminate (or else unambiguously mark the end of) the data in the array.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do such thing in C. The definition of your function

```
int monkey(int input[])
```

is formally equivalent to

```
int monkey(int *input)
```

so you ALWAYS need to pass the length of your array as an additional parameter

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
int array[10+1];
array[0] = 10;
// fill in the rest in array[1...10]
monkey(array);
// monkey() checks input1[0] to see how many data elements there are
```

and

```
int array[10+1];
array[0] = 10;
// fill in the rest in array[1...10]
monkey(array + 1);
// monkey() checks input1[-1] to see how many data elements there are
```

Alternatively, you can pass the size/count via a different channel, for example, a global variable, which you may guard with a critical section or a semaphore/lock if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass the array to the function, you can store the length as the first element of the array:

```
int monkey(int input1[])
{
    int len = input1[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        // do something with the array
    }
}

//...

int array[20];
array[0] = 20;
monkey(array);
```

An alternative method is to do it using pointer arithmetics instead, so that the function can treat the array as starting from 0:

```
int monkey(int input1[])
{
    int len = *(input1 - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        // do something with the array
    }
}

//...

int array[20];
array[0] = 19;
monkey(array + 1);
```

But it's the same thing really.  The only advantage this has is guarding against mistakes like starting from 0 instead of 1. But then this means that you could forget to pass `array + 1` when you call it. So meh.

Comment: @PaulR Look closer. I don't ;-)  The array length is 20, *including* the length specifier element. So useful data has a length of 19, and the `for` loop starts at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 62,34,4,4,4,3,2,-1 };

    monkey(arr);
    return 0;
}


int monkey(int input1[])
{
    int n = 0;

    while (a[n] != -1)
    {
        n++;
    }

    printf_s("Length of input1[] is: %d", n);

    return n;
}
```

Comment: And what if array doesn't contain `-1`?

Comment: No such limitation has been stated.You can set a different character instead of (-1), which will definitely be different from other elements of the array.

Answer (score -1):

int monkey(int input1[])
{

```
//Write code here
```

}

int len = sizeof(input1)/sizeof(input1[0]);
OR
int len = sizeof(input1)/sizeof(int);

is WRONG..
IT will always give 2..as input1 is a LONG POINTER AND so size is 8,,and sizeof(int) is 4..

if you want to find the length there is 2 ways...
1) pass the length...
( you cannot i suppose ) 
2) if you have idea..about the input1 array...say ( TECH GIG competition )
try to find out the number contained in the undefined parts of the array..
say here i found out for the sample ..{1,2,3,4,5} => input1[6] => contains the number -9999

so just wrote a while loop to find the length

while(input1[len]!=-9999)
len++;

to find out that 
input1[6] => contains the number -9999

i use in the answer
return input1[6]..to check 
that -9999 was the answer

i just submitted the answer for TECH GIG competition